# How to indent textual diff output of git show command

Tags: git

When I use `git show --no-prefix -U1000`, the result would be something like:

```
-var a = 0;
+const a = 0;

 no change
```

I'm wondering if there's an option to ident the line with a whitespace right after `+`/`-`, e.g.:

```
- var a = 0;
+ const a = 0;

  no change
```

I've checked the documentation here https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show, but there doesn't seem to be one.

Comment: Is this to change the format to something you find easier to read?

Comment: @Schwern Yes, that's my main purpose here.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the output through a script that will add a space if the first character is a space, +, or -.

```
git diff HEAD^ | perl -pe 's{^([ +-])(.)}{$1 $2}'
```

Also consider using [`git-difftool`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-difftool) to set up a diff viewing program to your liking.

Comment: This has the drawback of not preserving color and of altering a summary line like `--- a/README.md` to `- -- a/README.md`.

Comment: @SimonFromme Yes, to work 100% the script needs to parse the diff. Not difficult, but just furthering a hack. I would suggest using git-difftool instead, either with an existing tool, or a custom one.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a command-line flag to `git show` that inserts a space after the single `+` or `-` characters at the beginning of the diff (although you can change these very characters ever since [`2.22.0`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff/2.22.0) with [`--output-indicator-new=<char>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---output-indicator-newltchargt) or [`--output-indicator-old=<char>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---output-indicator-oldltchargt)).

What you could do is pipe the output to another program (e.g. `sed`) to insert the space "by hand" (assuming a terminal with sufficient color support):

```
git show --color=always | sed 's/^\x1B\[3[12]m[+-]/& /'
```

Note that:

1. The flag [`color=always`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---colorltwhengt) is necessary to preserve color codes when piping to a program that does not naturally support them.
2. We only insert a space after a single `+` or `-` character at the beginning of a line preceded by only the color codes `\x1B[32m` (green) or `\x1B[31m` (red). This is to avoid inserting unnecessary spaces in the summary lines (i.e. to prevent changing `--- a/foo` to `- -- a/foo`), in the commit message (which could theoretically begin with a `+` or `-`) or in the middle of the diff.

To avoid typing this command every time, you can define it as a [Git alias](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases) `my-show` (*Mind the leading `!` character in the alias-definition to treat the subsequent as an external command rather than a Git subcommand*).

```
git config --global alias.my-show "! git show --color=always | sed 's/^\x1B\[3[12]m[+-]/& /'"
```

and then invoke `git my-show` to get your desired output.

Comment: Yeah, `--output-indicator-new` only accepts one character, so it's not possible to work around with `--output-indicator-new="+ "`.